# how to upload an image to PostgreSQL database using asp.net core without MVC (Web API)

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

could anyone tell me, how can upload a profile picture to employee database (PostgreSQL) using asp.NET Core and Angular. please tell me the steps what I follow to do

Comment: What do you mean by "without MVC"? Do you already have a project that you want to add a new feature to, or do you plan to create a new web API application? Please provide more info about what you want to do.

Comment: Please clarify more about the question/requirement. Besides, to upload file from angular frontend to ASP.NET Core backend, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59352751/6751634 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230257/what-is-the-best-way-pass-file-from-angular-11-form-to-asp-net-core-5-web-api