# Null object error when reactJs file uploading using axios

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios

I am trying to upload an image using axios but it appears always to be null and I cant fix it. The post request get succeed with 201 but when I post request form frontend this gives null object error. I just can't configure why this is happening and a way of fixing this.

[This is the error popup in the controller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUB2P.png)

error says that ImageData is null. I have included my `reactjs` code along with this for your kind reference.
A part of the form which is to be submitted.

```js
export default class Upload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const pharmacyName = this.props.location.pharmacyName;
    this.state = {
      Date_time: "",
      Status: "",
      Status2: "",
      CustomerName: "",
      PatientName: "",
      PatientAge: 0,
      Address: "",
      Email: "",
      TeleNo: 0,
      Customer_id: 1,
      Pharmacy_id: 1,
      PharmacyName: pharmacyName ? pharmacyName : "",
      ImageData: null,
      Image:"",
      ImageSource: "",
    };
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "ImageData") {
      this.setState({
        ImageData: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ 
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
    console.log("final payload", this.state)
  };

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("e", e)
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    axios
      .post('/api/Orders', this.state)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      Date_time,
      Status,
      Status2,
      CustomerName,
      PatientName,
      PatientAge,
      Address,
      Email,
      TeleNo,
      Customer_id,
      Pharmacy_id,
      ImageData,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="outer">
        <div className="inner2">
          <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
            <h3>Upload Your Prescription Below</h3>
           
              <input
                type="file"
                name="ImageData"
                placeholder="Upload Your Prescription Here"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
              />
```

Controller:

```js
public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder([FromForm] Order order)
        {
            order.Image = await _iorderService.SaveImage(order.ImageData); //save image

            _context.Order.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return StatusCode(201);
        }
```

```
enter code here
```

Model class:

```js
 public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date_time { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Status2 { get; set; }
        public string PharmacyName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public int PatientAge { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int TeleNo { get; set; }
        public int Customer_id { get; set; }

        
        public string Image { get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile ImageData { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public String ImageSource { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Pharmacy")]
        public int Pharmacy_id { get; set; }
        //public Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OrderService.cs:

```js
public class OrderService : IOrderService
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
        public OrderService(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        }


        [NonAction]

        public async Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile ImageData)
        {
            string imageName = new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ImageData.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(' ', '-');
            imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(ImageData.FileName);
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Images", imageName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await ImageData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            return imageName;
        }

        [NonAction]
        public void DeleteImage(String imageName)
        {
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Images", imageName);
            if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                File.Delete(imagePath);


        }
    }
}
```

IOrderService.cs:

```js
{
    public interface IOrderService
    {
        Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile ImageData);

        void DeleteImage(String imageName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, exactly where are you getting this error? Your description is saying this is happening in React code, but your error screenshot is showing different code, which is not React code.
What is getting passed here in "ImageData"?

Comment: thank you very much for considering my issue. sir this error shows up in the controller code for this function. When I post request from frontend, this error pops up in the backend. But when I post request from postman, nothing goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to upload an image using axios but it appears always to be null and I cant fix it.

> ImageData: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])

> public async Task SaveImage(IFormFile ImageData)

Please note that the [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method would return a object URL of the specified File object or Blob object, you store that object URL in `ImageData` and pass to backend API action `SaveImage` that accepts a `IFormFile` type parameter, which would cause the posted data can not bound to parameter.

If you'd like to make request with selected file to your `SaveImage` endpoint, you can store `e.target.files[0]` directly instead of storing object URL, then make HTTP request with form data (populate with selected file(s)) from reactJS frontend using axios etc.

Comment: To upload file(s) from reactJS, Angular etc frontend to WebAPI backend, you can refer to this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854729/how-can-update-a-model-with-images-attach/64909637#64909637

Comment: Sir, Thank you very much for considering my issue. I changed my code as you said. But I still get the error I got before. Did I missed anything?   <code>  ImageData: e.target.files[0] </code> This is where I changed.

Comment: You can check the actual request and posted data in browser developer tool Network tab and compare it with that working request made from postman.

Comment: Sir I double checked the postman request and the post request I made through my actual request. The all were same. The only issue I recognized was that, in postman ImageData: Capture.png  But in actual request it showed as                                                                                            
  ImageData: File {name: "Capture.PNG", lastModified: 1616649095555, lastModifiedDate: Thu Mar 25 2021 10:41:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 140126, …} Is this an issue? Does my react js code is wrong?

Comment: If possible, you can share the screenshot of your posted data in browser developer tool Network tab, so that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.